# How to solve "Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries" when running spark code?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am learning spark + scala with intelliJ , started with below small piece of code

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object ActionsTransformations {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //Create a SparkContext to initialize Spark
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    conf.setMaster("local")
    conf.setAppName("Word Count")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val numbersList = sc.parallelize(1.to(10000).toList)

    println(numbersList)
  }

}
```

when trying to run , getting below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:127)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:501)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1218)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:481)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:210)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:353)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:446)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

can any one suggest what to do .

Comment: try `conf.setMaster("local[*]")`

Comment: see https://towardsdatascience.com/spark-fix-cant-assign-driver-32406580375

Answer (score 45):

Sometimes the problem is related to a connected VPN or something like that! Just disconnect your VPN or any other tool that may affect your networking, and then try again.

Comment: You just saved me a lot of pain.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Was on company VPN, although it was working previously, it suddenly started throwing this error, so disconnected from it and it started working.

Comment: This. Why is this not the top answer.

Answer (score 41):

Add SPARK_LOCAL_IP in load-spark-env.sh file located at spark/bin directory

export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="127.0.0.1"

Comment: This helped in my case. `master("local[*]")` did not.

Comment: Works for me, but the file is under spark/conf. You can use `echo "export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1" >> $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh` after defining `SPARK_HOME` if not already done..

Answer (score 35):

Seems like you've used some old version of spark. In your case try to add this line:

```
conf.set("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1")
```

If you will use spark 2.0+ folowing should do the trick:

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
.appName("Word Count")
.master("local[*]")
.config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1")
.getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 12):

The following should do the trick:

```
sudo hostname -s 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: This worked for me for github actions. Using this, didnt have to change the code for dev and integration env.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me for same error with pySpark:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf_spark = SparkConf().set("spark.driver.host", "127.0.0.1")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf_spark)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think *setMaster* and *setAppName* will return a new `SparkConf` object and the line `conf.setMaster("local")` will not effect on the `conf` variable. So you should try:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .setAppName("Word Count")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the ports which spark is trying to bind are already in use. Did this issue start happening after you ran spark successfully a few times?  You may want to check if those previously-run-spark-processes are still alive, and are holding onto some ports (a simple `jps` / `ps -ef` should tell you that). If yes, kill those processes and try again.

Comment: Notice: `Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)`. The error says it already tried 16 random free port!

Answer (score 0):

Add your hostname with your internal ip to `/etc/hosts`

### More explanation

Get your hostname with this command:

```sh
hostname
# OR
cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
```

Get your internal ip with this command:

```sh
ip a
```

Change values and add it to `/etc/hosts`

> ${INTERNAL_IP} ${HOSTNAME}

Example:

> 192.168.1.5 bashiri_pc

Or (Previous line is better!)

> 127.0.0.1 bashiri_pc