# Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark

I have a simple project connecting a postgres database to spark.  My project looks like this:

```
object Connector extends App {


runJdbcDatasetExample()

private def runJdbcDatasetExample(): Unit = {

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark SQL basic project")
  .config("spark.master", "local")
  .getOrCreate()

val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:5432")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "postgres")
  .option("password", "root")
  .load()

 }

}
```

I have a postgres database running on port 5432.  However when I run the project I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address
```

I can't figure out how to resolve this.  Grateful for help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries" when running spark code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52133731/how-to-solve-cant-assign-requested-address-service-sparkdriver-failed-after)