# Issues while connecting PySpark to a cassandra database

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra

I have a hard time trying to connecting PySpark to a Cassandra DB.

I am currently trying it with a SparkConf object:

```
pySparkConf = SparkConf().setAll([
    ['packages', 'com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0'],
    ['spark.cassandra.connection.host', '127.0.0.1'],
    ['spark.cassandra.connection.port', '9042']
])

sc = SparkContext(conf=pySparkConf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(
    table="emails", keyspace="lambda").load().show()
```

throws `java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.`

The configuration works on GNU/Linux, when it is passed to `os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS']`. It fails on the other OSes:

```py
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.port=9042 pyspark-shell'

sc = SparkContext("local", "PySpark email processing")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(
    table="emails", keyspace="lambda").load().show()
# Display the tables as expected
```

The packages installed in a virtual env:

```
cassandra-driver==3.24.0
py4j==0.10.9
pyspark==3.0.1
```

So how to connect the DB with a SparkConf or a SparkSession.builder object ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries" when running spark code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52133731/how-to-solve-cant-assign-requested-address-service-sparkdriver-failed-after)

Comment: @blackbishop Seems to be more a scala answer. Is the spark API the same for python?

Comment: @johannchopin although the config is the same `spark.driver.bindAddress`, the linked question contains also an answer for python.